# What is the difference between struct{int} and struct{int int}?

Tags: types, go

What is the difference between these two structs other than that they aren't considered equivalent?

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    a := struct{int}{1}
    b := struct{int int}{1}
    fmt.Println(a,b)
    a.int=2
    b.int=a.int
    fmt.Println(a,b)
    //a = b
}
```

They look the same:

```
$ go run a.go 
{1} {1}
{2} {2}
```

But if you uncomment `a = b`, it says:

```
$ go run a.go 
# command-line-arguments
./a.go:10: cannot use b (type struct { int int }) as type struct { int } in assignment
```

Yet `struct{a,b int}` and `struct{a int;b int}` are equivalent:

```
package main

func main() {
    a := struct{a,b int}{1,2}
    b := struct{a int;b int}{1,2}
    a = b
    b = a
}
```

?

Answer (score 9):

`struct { int }` is a struct with an anonymous field of type `int`.

`struct { int int }` is a struct with a field named `int` of type `int`.

`int` is not a keyword; it can be used as an identifier.

The struct types are not identical; the corresponding fields do not have the same names.

A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is an anonymous field and the unqualified type name acts as the anonymous field name. Therefore, field names `a.int` and `b.int` are valid. For example,

```
a := struct{ int }{1}
b := struct{ int int }{1}
a.int = 2
b.int = a.int
```

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Struct types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)
>
> A struct is a sequence of named elements, called fields, each of which
>   has a name and a type. Field names may be specified explicitly
>   (IdentifierList) or implicitly (AnonymousField). Within a struct,
>   non-blank field names must be unique.
>
> ```
> StructType     = "struct" "{" { FieldDecl ";" } "}" .
> FieldDecl      = (IdentifierList Type | AnonymousField) [ Tag ] .
> AnonymousField = [ "*" ] TypeName .
> ```
>
> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is an
>   anonymous field, also called an embedded field or an embedding of the
>   type in the struct. An embedded type must be specified as a type name
>   T or as a pointer to a non-interface type name *T, and T itself may
>   not be a pointer type. The unqualified type name acts as the field
>   name.
>
> [Keywords](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords)
>
> The following keywords are reserved and may not be used as
>   identifiers.
>
> ```
> break        default      func         interface    select
> case         defer        go           map          struct
> chan         else         goto         package      switch
> const        fallthrough  if           range        type
> continue     for          import       return       var
> ```
>
> [Type identity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)
>
> Two struct types are identical if they have the same sequence of
>   fields, and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical
>   types, and identical tags. Two anonymous fields are considered to have
>   the same name. Lower-case field names from different packages are
>   always different.

Comment: The fields don't have the same name? Then why do both `a.int` and `b.int` work?

Comment: @Dog: For an anonymous field, the unqualified type name acts as the anonymous field name. See my revised answer.

Comment: I think the idea (correct me if I'm wrong, @peterSO) is that while `int` can be used to access the field, it's not the name of the field in the same was that `a` is the name of the field in `struct{ a int }` (and thus isn't the name for purposes of type equality).

Comment: @synful: Yes, there are two questions. First, are the two types identical (exactly the same)? The type identity rules apply; the explicit field names must be exactly the same. Second, how can we refer to the anonymous field? The unqualified type name acts as the implicit field name.

Comment: What you pasted just seems to imply that `struct{int}=struct{int int}`. But I don't think there's not enough information here to know for sure. In either case, I'm looking for what's actually different about the two types other than that the compiler considers them different.

Comment: @Dog: No, as The Go Programming Language Specification type identity rules clearly state, `struct { int }` is not identical to `struct { int int }`, they are not exactly the same. An anonymous field (explicitly no name) cannot have exactly the same name as a explictly named field. By design, the Go programming language is simple, straightforward, and orthogonal. The specification is only about 50 pages long. In Go, type identity simply means identical in all respects. There is no reason to make it more complicated than that.